# fetch rows from table based on from and to dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table as shown here:
[image]

---

In the table there are two columns named  `DateFrom` and `DateTo`.

I want to fetch row data from or between these two dates. e.g. If I want to fetch data from `2018-12-27` to `2019-01-10` it should return the two rows with `HPID`  `1` and `6` - as both row have or comes under the mentioned dates.

Now I don't know what the SQL query should be. I have tried `BETWEEN` but with no result.

Actually I am working on a small hotel management system and the table shows the cost of any hotel between certain dates. So when the user searches for hotels for date between two dates it should show costs which overlap those dates.

DateFrom and DateTo Are not datetime.

Comment: Actually i am working on a small hotel management system and in my database i have two column DateFrom and DateTo cost of any hotel changes according to these column Dates means when user search for hotel for date between 2018-12-27 to 2019-01-10 it should show some cost other than this date it should show other cost
Columns: DateFrom and DateTo Are not datetime

Answer (score 0):

[Stefan Taseki's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53760719/5947043) is almost right but doesn't deal with overlaps correctly. Swap the start and end dates round in that query and it should do the job:

```
SELECT *
FROM [YourTable]
WHERE DateFrom <= '2019-01-10' AND DateTo >= '2018-12-27'
```

---

P.S. You should **always** store your dates in `datetime` columns. Dates are not text. You will have issues with a) sorting, b) comparisons, and c) presenting dates in different formats if you don't do this. The `datetime` data type exists for good reasons, you should use it. Consider changing your database now while you can.

P.P.S. Your data is also de-normalised. Country, City, HotelName, HotelCode and HotelStar should all be in a separate "hotel" table (and country and city each should be in different tables too), and then with a foreign key on Hotel ID only in this costs table. Otherwise you keep repeating data which should only be entered once. I suggest you learn about relational database design and normalisation, if you didn't realise this.

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM [YourTable]
WHERE DateFrom >= '2018-12-27' AND DateTo<= 2019-01-10
```

Comment: for particular above date mysql returns results but if i try to run DateFrom >= '2018-12-30' AND DateTo<= 2019-01-05 no results..

Answer (score -1):

First of all make sure that your dates are in single quotes

```
'SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE DateFrom BETWEEN '2018-12-27' and '2019-01-10' OR DateTo BETWEEN '2018-12-27' and '2019-01-10';
```

Something that is not clear is what are you trying to achieve with this query.

Answer (score -1):

Casting may be required, use below query

```
select *from your_table_name 
where date(DateFrom) >= date('2018-11-27') AND date(DateTo) <= date('2019-01-10')
```